# NameError Redis on Rails 7 app on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, redis, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elasticache

I am trying to connect Elastic Cache Redis to my Rails 7 app and it gives me this error as if it does not know 'redis'.

```
2023/08/14 13:25:30.632645 [INFO] Running command /bin/su webapp -c bundle exec rake assets:precompile
2023/08/14 13:25:31.595513 [INFO] rake aborted!
NameError: undefined local variable or method `redis' for main:Object
Did you mean?  redo
```

I have redis gem and Elastic Cache configured like this in `production.rb`:

```
config.cache_store = :redis_cache_store, { URL: ENV["REDIS_PRIMARY_ENDPOINT"] }
```